# Dónde está el bug en esta Funcion Para Comparar Array con un número

Tags: javascript

Esta es una función que compara un array con un número `(target)`. Se trata de devolver los índices del array dónde se encuentra los 2 números que sumados dan como resultado el número `(target)`

En los dos casos que pongo como ejemplo funciona correctamente:

```js
const letSum = (array, target) => {

  let arr = []
  
    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      let difference = target - array[i]
      arr.push(difference)

      if (array.includes(difference)){
        var first = difference;
        var second = array[i]
      }
    }

    let finalArr = [array.indexOf(first),array.indexOf(second)]
    return finalArr
  }

console.log(letSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9)); // returns [0,1]
console.log(letSum([3,2,4], 6)); // returns [1,2]
```

Sin embargo en casos como este:

```
console.log(letSum([3,3], 6)); // returns [0,0]
```

Devuelve [0,0] cuando evidentemente debería devolver [0,1]

Comment: Si no me equivoco, el problema está en que son números iguales, es decir, es dos veces el mismo número. Cuando recorre el `array` de nuevo para comprobar si la diferencia está en el `array`, vuelve a encontrar el primero, que cumple la condición. Por lo tanto, te devuelve que el número en la posición cero + el número en la posición cero dan como resultado el número buscado

Comment: El método `indexOf()` devuelve el índice, dentro del objeto String que realiza la llamada, de la primera ocurrencia del valor especificado [mas info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf). Al tener 2 veces el mismo numero te suma la primera ocurrencia que encuentra, las 2 veces son 3 por lo que la posicion es 0

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que buscas en todo el array. Los métodos `includes` e `indexOf` aceptan un segundo parámetro que es el índice desde el que empezar a buscar, podrías solucionar el problema indicando que quieres buscar desde la posición siguiente a la actual.

Por otro lado, creo que te estás complicando: para una posición `i`, busca la siguiente posición que contenga la diferencia calculada. Si la encuentras, devuelves los elementos que están en la posición `i` y en la posición encontrada:

```js
const letSum = (array, target) => {
 for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let difference = target - array[i];
    //el 2º parámetro indica desde donde buscar
    let indexDif = array.indexOf(difference, i + 1); 
    if (indexDif > -1) {
      return [i, indexDif];
    }
  }
}

console.log(letSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9));
console.log(letSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 18));
console.log(letSum([3, 2, 4], 6)); 
console.log(letSum([3, 3, 4], 6));
```

Además de esta forma sabes si el resultado es válido: tu función siempre devuelve un array, incluso si no hubiese resultado. Esta función no devuelve nada (o devuelve `undefined`, según quieras verlo) cuando no se encuentra una pareja de números.